# Android & Unity3D - Unity's generated R.java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, unity-game-engine, r.java-file

So for my Unity game I am making a simple plugin to display ads. I display the ad using a linear layout. Outside of Unity, I can get an ad working just fine using the linear layout. In Unity (after making the proper changes such that my activity extends UnityPlayerActivity) my game's activity runs until it reaches this line:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

I have linearLayout in my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">  
</LinearLayout>
```

Putting res/layout/activity_main.xml in Plugins/Android doesn't fix anything. I suspect the problem is my Unity application cannot find linearLayout in its R.java. I don't know how to make it so Unity builds R.java with my linearLayout. What do I do?

**EDIT:** I have confirmed that linearLayout is indeed in Unity's generated R.java:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int app_icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int linearLayout=0x7f060000;
    }
    public static final class integer {
        public static final int google_play_services_version=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Thus something else is crashing my app when calling that single line. But what?

**EDIT 2:**

Here is what my LogCat looks like everytime I try to run the app (it closes instantly when I try to run it)

> 05-15 14:12:35.223: E/jdwp(20666): Failed sending b-req to debugger: Broken pipe (-1 of 89)
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.253: W/dalvikvm(20666): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   field 5143 (linearLayout) in Lcom/mycompany/mygame/R$id;
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.253: D/dalvikvm(20666): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at
>   0x0023
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.283: D/dalvikvm(20666): Trying to load lib
>   /mnt/asec/com.mycompany.mygame-1/lib/libmain.so 0x31957170
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.283: D/dalvikvm(20666): Added shared lib
>   /mnt/asec/com.mycompany.mygame-1/lib/libmain.so 0x31957170
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/OverrideActivity(20666): onCreate called... ...
>   ...
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/OverrideActivity(20666): I got this far! 1
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/OverrideActivity(20666): I got this far! 2^
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/AndroidRuntime(20666): Shutting down VM
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: W/dalvikvm(20666): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x313c61f8)
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/AndroidRuntime(20666): procName from cmdline:
>   com.mycompany.mygame
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: E/AndroidRuntime(20666): in writeCrashedAppName,
>   pkgName :com.mycompany.mygame
>
> 05-15 14:12:35.363: D/AndroidRuntime(20666): file written successfully
>   with content: com.mycompany.mygame StringBuffer :
>   ;com.mycompany.mygame

Here is what MainActivity.java looks like:

```
package com.mycompany.mygame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3778961516243228/8122389190";
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // call UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // print debug message to logcat
    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "onCreate called... ... ...");
    newAd();
}

void newAd() {
    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 1");

    // Create ad view
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 2^");

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. No size until ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 2.5");

    layout.addView(adView);

    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 3");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 4");

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    Log.d("OverrideActivity", "I got this far! 5");
}

void killAd() {
    adView.destroy();
}
}
```

Also my Manifest in Plugins/Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mycompany.mygame">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATS"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name="com.mycompany.mygame.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Please post the crash log also for us to better understand your problem and thus providing a better solution.

Comment: I have added the logcat

Answer (score 0):

The error is apparent and it will come the reason is simple there is no layout specified form where `findViewById()` will get the linearlayout.If you see the linearlayout in R its in "id" field but program is not able to access it because you have not loaded the xml file where this id (linearlayout) is present and also it should be BEFORE THE findViewById() is called.

Once try this because i guess you need to add a new LinearLayout ,

A. so instead of `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);` you need to do something like this `LinearLayout dynamicLinear=new LinearLayout(this);dynamicLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);int id=1234;dynamicLinear.setId(id);dynamicLinear.addView(adView);`

OR

B. Replace `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);` 
    with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)             findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);` I assumed you have the linearLayout id in activity_main.xml also i can see only dat layout in the R file hence i put like that.

Hope this fix your problem...

thx

Comment: So linearLayout is now being generated in R.java, so it looks like my problem is something else with that single line...

Comment: can u let me the error ? is it null pointer or something else ? also what the package names for main activity and unity game package plzzz...

Comment: I think I added the info you wanted

Comment: Thank you, this has at least brought me closer. However, when I do the first option, I get messages from the catlog saying that an ad is loaded and ready to display, but isn't visible, despite various resizing methods I have tried. If I try the second option, my game still crashes when I reach the "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but 
Now you can some step a head.  such as
1. delete Android.R (in above in your activity )
2. or replace package.R for example , com.example.name.R
3. check you res folder or sub-folder resources .such as layout attribute right or not.
4. Delete gen and bin folder.
5. clean your project thus: project=>clean
6. restart your eclipse.

Remember that if your resource not found then show this type error.

Best of luck!